# How to get specific digits only after a word Python regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string like so :

```
'$."result"."000182"."200"', '$."result"."000490"."200"', '$."result"."000530"."200"'
```

I want to get an array of the results of the digits after the

`"result"."[WANTOGETTHISNUMBER]"."200"`

I tried something like this ( example )

```
test_str = "'$.""result"".""000109"".""200""', '$.""result"".""000110"".""200""', '$.""result"".""000111"".""200""', '$.""result"".""000112"".""200""'"

x = re.findall('[0-9]+', test_str)

print(x)
#['000109', '200', '000110', '200', '000111', '200', '000112', '200']
```

But I want output as : `['000109', '000110',  '000111',  '000112']`

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Use a positive lookbehind. https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Question - your test string doesn't contain all the double quotes, due to the way it was created (in python). In that your purpose?

Comment: @Roy2012 yes, actually thats the original string but to test it in python, I escaped the double quotes with double quotes :-P

Comment: Do you wish to extract every string that is preceded by `"result"."` and is followed by `"200"`? If so, you need to say that. "...want to get an array of the results of the digits after the `"result"."[WANTOGETTHISNUMBER]"."200"` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
>>> re.findall('result\.([0-9]+)', test_str)
['000109', '000110', '000111', '000112']
```

Comment: Also, [a Python demo online](https://ideone.com/DhsNho).

Comment: I tried something almost similar but was not getting results. :-P `re.findall('"result"\."(\d+)"', str` Thanks :-)

Comment: @SankalpSingha It failed because double quotes were not in your string. Try printing this string: `"Hello this ""is a test"" string"` At the end, it creates your string by concatenating 3 strings: `"Hello this " + "is a test" + " string"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that takes the excessive quotes into account:

```
test_str = """ '$.""result"".""000109"".""200""', '$.""result"".""000110"".""200""', '$.""result"".""000111"".""200""', '$.""result"".""000112"".""200""'" """

re.findall(r"result\"\".\"\"(\d+)", test_str)
```

The result is:

```
['000109', '000110', '000111', '000112']
```

Answer (score -1):

Find numbers of Specific Length in String

To find numbers of specific length, N, is a string, use the regular expression [0-9]+ to find number strings of any length. [0-9] matches a single digit. After you find all the items, filter them with the length specified.

Example 1: Find numbers of specific length in a string

In the following example, we take a string, and find all the 3 digit numbers in that string.

Python Program

`
import re
s tr = """We four guys, live at 2nd street     of Malibeu 521. I had a cash of $248 in my pocket.   I got a ticket with serial number 88796451-52."""
#search using regex
x = re.findall('[0-9]+', str)
print('All Numbers\n',x)
#digits of length N
N=3
def filterNumber(n):
if(len(n)==N):
return True
else:
return False
#filter the list
finalx = list(filter(filterNumber, x))
print('Final List\n',finalx)

```
Output

All Numbers ['2', '521', '248', '88796451', '52'].          
Final List ['521', '248']`
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked and is giving a completely random use case.